# For any $n-1$ elements of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, we can make $0$ using $\{-,+,\times\}$ without parentheses

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, algebraic-number-theory, additive-combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

*MSE: [Just using $+$ ,$-$, $\times$ using any given n-1 integers, can we make a number divisible by n? (no brackets allowed)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4078978/318073)*

---

Is there any hope in proving the following? *(Cross-posted here after a bounty and a month on MSE.)*

> Let $n\gt 2$. For any $n-1$ elements of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, we can make $0$ using $\{-,+,\times\}$ without parentheses.

Note that:

- It seems that even a stronger claim of using only $\{-,\times\}$ holds for $n\gt 5$? *(Verified up to $n\le 12$ by exhaustive brute force.)*
- It is known that if we allow only $\{-,+\}$, then the claim holds if and only if $n$ is an odd prime. *(This is a consequence of the [Cauchy-Davenport theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_sumset#Cauchy%E2%80%93Davenport_theorem). See MSE post [For any $n-1$ non-zero elements of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, we can make zero using $+,-$ if and only if $n$ is prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4094506/318073).)*

Therefore, it remains to consider only composite $n$ greater than $12$.

There are only $\binom{2n-3}{n-1}$ multisets $a_1,...,a_{n-1} \ne 0$ to consider, for given $n$. *(If any element were equal to $0$, multiplication would be sufficient.)*

If it is too hard to make any more progress, would it be any easier if we make the same claim but allow more operations?

---

Note that if parentheses were allowed, then the claim would be trivial. If any of the elements $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{n-1}$ is equal to zero ($\exists i : a_i=0$) or not distinct $(\exists i\ne j : a_i=a_j)$, then we multiply everything with $a_i=0$ or with $(a_i-a_j)=0$ to get a zero. Therefore, it remains to consider $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{n-1}=1,2,\dots,n-1$, in which case, multiply everything with $(1+(n-1))=0$ to get a zero.

Comment: Do you really mean elements of $\mathbb Z/n$ (so taken modulo $n$) or $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}\subseteq\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @Wojowu We are working modulo $n$. (notice that $n\equiv 0$ is used in the last note)